# Grouping a List of Items using java 8 Streams and populating resulting Map with FIRST Item rather than List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an item defined by the following class:

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private float price;
}
```

I've been given a list of items and I need to group them by **id**. Once grouped, I know the List will only ever contain a single value for each id, so I want the resulting Map to be defined as follows:

```
Map<Integer, Item>
```

rather than:

```
Map<Integer, List<Item>>
```

The benefit of this, is that my calling code will not need to perform extra dereferencing:

mapName.get(id)**.get(0)**

The following code will group the items by id and create a Map containing a list:

```
Map<Integer, List<Item>> itemsMap = itemList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId));
```

Is there a way in Java 8 to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:
`Map<Integer, Item> itemsMap = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, Function.<Item>identity()));`

Answer (score 2):

```
itemList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.id, item -> item));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do around such conversions using IDE's such as intelliJ is:

```
List<Item> itemList = ...
Map<Integer, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Item item : itemList) {
    itemMap.put(item.getId(), item);
}
```

and then convert/replace the statement as:

```
Map<Integer, Item> itemMap =
            itemList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getId, item -> item, (a, b) -> b));
```

which is same as [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342041/1746118).

Comment: Good point. I'll use the IDE's capability if in doubt in future.

Comment: I wouldn’t use a merge function like `(a, b) -> b` when the OP asserts that there is only one item. Either, don’t specify a merge function and let it throw when the assertion does not hold, or specify `(a,b)->a` to reduce to the *first* item to match the question’s title, rather than the last item…